# navigation component using sightly

Tags: navigation, aem, sightly

I am trying to make use of Navigation api for making a global header component @http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/foundation/Navigation.html
I have a sightly html that is able to get me the reference to the "item"

```
<div data-sly-unwrap data-sly-use.navitems="${'Helper'}"></div> 
<ul data-sly-list="${navitems.navigationIterator}">
    <li> ${itemList.count} ::  ${item.page.properties.jcr:primaryType} :: ${item.title} 
        ${item.navigation.element.properties.Type}
    </li>
```

Helper class is returning the iterator for using as a list and parsing over the itemsList. Helper class method is like this:

```
public Iterator getNavigationIterator() {
     Navigation nav = new Navigation(getCurrentPage() , absParent , new PageFilter(getRequest()), 3);
     return nav.iterator();
}
```

**What I able to do:**

I am able to access the page properties(and any custom properties). I am able to print the entire tree structure

**What I can't get to:**

*I am unable to retrieve the Navigation.Element.Type  property from the item.*
To make a 'UL' and 'LI' structure, I need to identify what is the Navigation.Element.Type for the item in question.

Does anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

The iterator goes through all Navigation.Element entries. Therefor you should be able to access this field by using

```
item.type
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
data-sly-test=${item.listChidlren}
```

Or simply

```
<ul data-sly-list=${currentPage.listChildren}>
```

Comment: I have to try it yet... I'll do it over the long weekend and revert for sure. 
I dropped using Navigation as It wasn't working in time for my delivery date and moved to a 'listchildren' instead .... this worked for me !