# Using Navigation API In Sightly AEM

Tags: aem, sightly

I am trying to use navigation api in sightly.

Following the link : [navigation component using sightly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29157361/navigation-component-using-sightly)

I am getting the list of pages,but ${item.type} is not working for me,thats why i am not able to apply proper DOM structure(html of the component).
Can anyone please help me?

Comment: The Stack Overflow moderators won't like this one. Rather than creating a new question that just links to another question, you should up vote the original question and add a comment with additional details to help the community solve the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [javadocs](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/foundation/Navigation.html), `navigation.getIterator()` returns `Navigation.Element`, so the method returns iterator of `Navigation.Element`-

```
    public Iterator getNavigationIterator() {
     Navigation nav = new Navigation(getCurrentPage() , absParent , new PageFilter(getRequest()), 3);
     return nav.iterator();
}
```

The sightly expression will look something like -

```
<ul data-sly-list.navElement="${navitems.navigationIterator}">
    <li>
        ${navElement.type}
    </li>
</ul>
```